# Collecting multiple files as an output of a nextflow process and making a new queue

Tags: nextflow

I have a nextflow process that looks like this

```
process TileImages {

    input:
        val run_id
        val group_id
        val sample_id
        path image
        path masks

    output:
        val run_id, emit: run_id
        val group_id, emit: group_id
        val sample_id, emit: sample_id
    
    script:
        """
        python ${projectDir}/bin/run-tile-images.py \
            --image ${image} \
            --masks ${masks} 
        """

}
```

This calls a Python script that ends like this

```
i = 0
for wsi_patch, mask_patch in zip(wsi_patch_extractor, mask_patch_extractor):
    np.save(f"{args.prefix}_wsi_{i}.npy", wsi_patch)
    np.save(f"{args.prefix}_mask_{i}.npy", mask_patch)
    i += 1
```

Rather than saving and passing on one file, this saves roughly 40 file pairs (not the same number each time). How can I write the Nextflow process such that each of these pairs is a new entry in the output queue?

I.e. the output of a single process would in fact be lots of outputs each containing the run_id, group_id and sample_id as well as one of the wsi/mask pairs that are saved out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to group the files by their suffix and then use the key to collect the file pairs. Note that we can use the [`flatMap`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#flatmap) operator to emit the items in the collection separately. For example:

```
process test {

    input:
    val sample_id

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_{wsi,mask}_*.npy")

    """
    for i in {1..3} ; do
        touch "${sample_id}_wsi_\${i}.npy"
        touch "${sample_id}_mask_\${i}.npy"
    done
    """
}

workflow {

    samples = Channel.of( 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' )

    test( samples )

    test.out.flatMap { sample, files ->
      files
        .groupBy { it.baseName.split('_',)[-1] }
        .collect { key, values ->
            def mask = values.find { it.baseName.endsWith("_mask_${key}") }
            def wsi = values.find { it.baseName.endsWith("_wsi_${key}") }

            tuple( sample, mask, wsi )
        }
    }.view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [scruffy_feynman] DSL2 - revision: 8d78366a9a
executor >  local (3)
[d4/0acae5] process > test (3) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[bar, /path/to/work/c5/228fa4aaf6e65675b93158397d4657/bar_mask_1.npy, /path/to/work/c5/228fa4aaf6e65675b93158397d4657/bar_wsi_1.npy]
[bar, /path/to/work/c5/228fa4aaf6e65675b93158397d4657/bar_mask_2.npy, /path/to/work/c5/228fa4aaf6e65675b93158397d4657/bar_wsi_2.npy]
[bar, /path/to/work/c5/228fa4aaf6e65675b93158397d4657/bar_mask_3.npy, /path/to/work/c5/228fa4aaf6e65675b93158397d4657/bar_wsi_3.npy]
[foo, /path/to/work/89/d26cde15264689c2194027b59042c3/foo_mask_1.npy, /path/to/work/89/d26cde15264689c2194027b59042c3/foo_wsi_1.npy]
[foo, /path/to/work/89/d26cde15264689c2194027b59042c3/foo_mask_2.npy, /path/to/work/89/d26cde15264689c2194027b59042c3/foo_wsi_2.npy]
[foo, /path/to/work/89/d26cde15264689c2194027b59042c3/foo_mask_3.npy, /path/to/work/89/d26cde15264689c2194027b59042c3/foo_wsi_3.npy]
[baz, /path/to/work/d4/0acae55ebb3ef87ab49d12ae988041/baz_mask_1.npy, /path/to/work/d4/0acae55ebb3ef87ab49d12ae988041/baz_wsi_1.npy]
[baz, /path/to/work/d4/0acae55ebb3ef87ab49d12ae988041/baz_mask_2.npy, /path/to/work/d4/0acae55ebb3ef87ab49d12ae988041/baz_wsi_2.npy]
[baz, /path/to/work/d4/0acae55ebb3ef87ab49d12ae988041/baz_mask_3.npy, /path/to/work/d4/0acae55ebb3ef87ab49d12ae988041/baz_wsi_3.npy]
```

Comment: That's awesome and does exactly what I want!!! Thank you!!!